# Difference between Isomorphism and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

What exactly is the difference between them?
It says in my textbook that a plane in R3 could be isomorphic to R2 but R2 can never be a subspace of R3. What exactly is the difference between them? Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: Something is wrong. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is (isomorphic to) a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Please check what the textbook says.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan What's wrong? It is common convention to consider ordered pairs and ordered triples to never be equal, so these two vector spaces have no elements in common, so $\Bbb R^2$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^3$. There is of course a canonical identification of $\Bbb R^2$ with the obvious subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ though.

Comment: For one thing, a subspace is a subset, an isomorphism is a function, and the adjective "isomorphic" describes a pair of mathematical objects (such as vector spaces), so they are definitely different words. This is analogous to asking the difference between the words "subset," "function" and "same size."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\rm\{apple,orange,banana\}$ are "isomorphic" as sets (the only structural property of a set is how many elements it has, so two sets are isomorphic if they have the same number of elements), but they are not the same set.

(For infinite sets, the "number of" elements is actually understood in terms of equivalence classes of sets under bijections, which are isomorphisms of sets, so this is arguably backwards thinking if you want to understand set theory at some point. End tangent.)

The same idea holds with vector spaces. The structure of a vector space is the addition operation and the multiplication by scalars operation. Two vector spaces are isomorphic if  there is a one-to-one correspondence between their elements that preserve these two operations. But that does not mean two isomorphic vector spaces are the same space - they can have different elements.

For example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a set of ordered triples $(x,y,z)$. An ordered pair never equals an ordered triple any more than an apple can equal a doorknob, and so we conclude $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ have no elements in common, therefore certainly $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ because that would presuppose it's a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which it isn't.

On the other hand, consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all elements of the form $(x,y,0)$; you can check for yourself this subset satisfies the axioms for being called a subspace (closed under addition and scalar multiplication). There is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of ordered triples $(x,y,0)$ and the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, namely $(x,y,0)\leftrightarrow(x,y)$. In fact this correspondence preserves the addition and scalar multiplication operations, so it is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Answer (score 4):

We say that $V$ is a subspace of a $W$ if $V \subseteq W$ and $V$ is closed under linear combinations i.e. if $v, w \in V$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{k}$ (in this case $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{R}$), then $av + bw \in V$. $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ becase it's not a subset of the latter to begin with.

There can be, however, vector space isomorphisms between a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore, if two vector spaces are finite dimensional, they are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. Since a plane (not any plane though, it must be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$) is a vector space on it's own with the operations induced by $\mathbb{R}^3$ and has dimension 2, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinction between saying that $A$ is a subspace of $B$ and saying that $A$ is *isomorphic to* a subspace of $B$.

Being a subspace is significantly more restrictive than just being isomorphic to a subspace. Being a subspace means that the very points themselves, not just copies of them, are in both spaces.

So, the collection of points of the form $(r,0)$ forms a subspace of the plane $\mathbb R^2$. This subspace is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. It is a line in the plane, but it isn't really $\mathbb R$; rather, it is $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$.

The distinction is subtle. You can think of identifying points in $\mathbb R$ with points in $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ via $r \leftrightarrow (r,0)$, but in the end, points of $\mathbb R$ are single numbers while points in $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ are pairs of numbers (which always happen to have $0$ as the second number).

Note that there are many subspaces of the plane which are isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. For example, I could have said $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$, or picked any line through the origin.